# custom Keyboard without android.inputmethodservice.Keyboard

Tags: java, android, kotlin, keyboard, libraries

I want to have a custom keyboard for some of my input.
I found the `android.inputmethodservice.Keyboard` library but now it's deprecated. There is a way to do custom keyboard whithout use this library ?

Thanks for your answers !

Answer (score 0):

[DOC](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/Keyboard) says:

> This class was deprecated in API level 29.
> This class is deprecated because this is just a convenient UI widget class that application developers can re-implement on top of existing public APIs. If you have already depended on this class, **consider copying the implementation from AOSP into your project** or re-implementing a similar widget by yourselves

[HERE](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/inputmethodservice/Keyboard.java) you have source for copying `Keyboard` class to your project

Comment: thanks for the tips, i've already try to do that but ni success, there is no keyboard pop when i using my Keyboard class updated from your link. Maybe i can show my class, and you can see what i'm doing wrong ?

Comment: sadly I don't have much experience in this topic, just suggested whan doc suggests...